# Target depends on file to be created

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What's the easiest way to make a target depend on a file to be created, inside its recipe? I could use some shell magic:

```
target:
        [ -e file ] || touch file
```

But ideally, I'd like to leave the test with make. Is it possible? The target commands should only run if the file doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give more information about what you're trying to accomplish, we may be able to help you better.  Based on what you've said so far, it sounds like regular old `make` prerequisites should do the trick for you:

```
target: file
        touch target

file:
        touch file
```

If `file` does not exist, it will be created; if it does, the commands for `file` will not be executed.

Comment: Thanks Eric! And sorry for the little information provided, I just tried to reduce it at maximum. I was trying something more direct, like `target: file(\n)(\t)touch file`, which didn't work. I thought that having the file name as a prerequisite would be enough —should go back to some basics.